# How to select results from table #1 filtered by results in table #2?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, filter

Well, I have two tables:

- `events` : `id`, `title`, `description`
- `trip_events` : `id`, `event_id` (points to `events`.`id`)

I need to select results from table named `events`.

```
SELECT *
FROM `events`
```

Simple as that, right?

The thing I need to achieve is that I need to select results from `events`, but exclude those rows that are in `trip_events` (if `events`.`id` != `trip_events`.`event_id` the excluded).

Here is example:

`events`:

- `id` : `5`,
- `id` : `6`,
- `id` : `7`,
- `id` : `8`;

`trip_events`:

- `event_id` : `6`,
- `event_id` : `8`;

With this data-set, only events with id as `5` and `6` would be returned.

How to do this?

I tried like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `events`
JOIN `trip_events`
ON (`trip_events`.`event_id` = `events`.`id`)
WHERE `trip_events`.`event_id` != `events`.`id`
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from events where id not in
(select event_id from trip_events)
```

**Edit:**
As a side note, the `ON` condition can be thought of as a `WHERE` condition. The result of your query would be the same as the following

```
SELECT *
FROM `events`
JOIN `trip_events`
ON 1 = 1
WHERE (`trip_events`.`event_id`  = `events`.`id`)
AND   (`trip_events`.`event_id` != `events`.`id`)
```

Guess why you don't get any results!

Comment: Anyway I think solution with join will be better for performance reasons.

Comment: @4ndrew, yes, might be, but as long as performance is not an issue (and the join query is actually faster) I think this is more readable and obvious in its intent. The left join idiom is well known, but you need to know the idiom and identify what idiom that is used before you can read the code.

Comment: @4ndrew: You can't know what is faster until you test - with your data. And as far as I know, `NOT IN` vs. `NOT EXISTS` vs `LEFT JOIN - IS NULL` have similar performance.

Comment: @Albin: +1 for the xplanation on why the OP's query fails.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to solve this problem (using left join instead of subselect):

```
SELECT events.id from events
    LEFT JOIN trip_events on events.id = trip_events.event_id
    WHERE trip_events.event_id is null;
```

In some cases it can be better than variant with subselect proposed by [@Albin Sunnanbo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8677697/159874) from performance point, it depends on which SQL server you are using (some servers performs better optimization in such cases both variants provides the same performance).

Comment: The query is correct but it's not an inner join. It's a (left) outer join.

Comment: @ypercube Ops, sorry, it's a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from events e 
where not exists (
    select 1 from trip_events t 
    where t.event_id = e.id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below Query:

SELECT *
    FROM `events`
    WHERE id not in (select event_id from trip_events)